# This procedure is inserting null values into my custom table - why?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SRM_H_PROC(
    EMPLID_OUT OUT VARCHAR2,
    ACAD_CAREER_OUT OUT VARCHAR2,
    ACAD_PROG_INOUT IN OUT VARCHAR2,
    PROG_STATUS_OUT OUT VARCHAR2,
    ADMIT_TERM_INOUT IN OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
  CURSOR PROC2
  IS
    SELECT
      A.EMPLID,
      A.ACAD_CAREER,
      A.ACAD_PROG,
      A.PROG_STATUS,
      A.ADMIT_TERM
    FROM
      PS_ACAD_PROG A
    WHERE
      A.ADMIT_TERM  = ADMIT_TERM_INOUT
    AND A.ACAD_PROG =ACAD_PROG_INOUT
    AND A.EFFDT     =
      (
        SELECT MAX(EFFDT) FROM PS_ACAD_PROG WHERE EMPLID=A.EMPLID
      )
  AND A.EFFSEQ=
    (
      SELECT
        MAX(EFFSEQ)
      FROM
        PS_ACAD_PROG
      WHERE
        EMPLID =A.EMPLID
      AND EFFDT=A.EFFDT
    )
  AND A.PROG_STATUS='AC';
BEGIN
  FOR I IN PROC2
  LOOP
    IF ADMIT_TERM_INOUT='1701' THEN
      INSERT
      INTO
        PS_SRM_H_PROC_TB VALUES
        (
          EMPLID_OUT,
          ACAD_CAREER_OUT,
          ACAD_PROG_INOUT,
          PROG_STATUS_OUT,
          ADMIT_TERM_INOUT
        );
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HI DEAR, SAY HELLO TO ME.');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END SRM_H_PROC;
```

Table output is like this when I pass acad_prog 'BTRCS' and admit_term '1701' as input in procedure:

```
(NULL)  (NULL)  BTRCS   (NULL)  1701
(NULL)  (NULL)  BTRCS   (NULL)  1701
(NULL)  (NULL)  BTRCS   (NULL)  1701
(NULL)  (NULL)  BTRCS   (NULL)  1701
(NULL)  (NULL)  BTRCS   (NULL)  1701
(NULL)  (NULL)  BTRCS   (NULL)  1701
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `cursor` values in `if` statement and in `insert` statement like this:

```
FOR I IN PROC2
  LOOP
    IF I.ADMIT_TERM ='1701' THEN
      INSERT
      INTO
        PS_SRM_H_PROC_TB VALUES
        (
          I.EMPLID,
          I.ACAD_CAREER,
          I.ACAD_PROG,
          I.PROG_STATUS,
          I.ADMIT_TERM
        );
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HI DEAR, SAY HELLO TO ME.');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
```

This can also be done using `insert into .. select ..` (without `cursor`) as following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SRM_H_PROC(
    EMPLID_OUT OUT VARCHAR2,
    ACAD_CAREER_OUT OUT VARCHAR2,
    ACAD_PROG_INOUT IN OUT VARCHAR2,
    PROG_STATUS_OUT OUT VARCHAR2,
    ADMIT_TERM_INOUT IN OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN 
      INSERT
      INTO
        PS_SRM_H_PROC_TB 
      SELECT
      A.EMPLID,
      A.ACAD_CAREER,
      A.ACAD_PROG,
      A.PROG_STATUS,
      A.ADMIT_TERM
    FROM
      PS_ACAD_PROG A
    WHERE
      A.ADMIT_TERM  = ADMIT_TERM_INOUT
    AND A.ACAD_PROG =ACAD_PROG_INOUT
    AND A.EFFDT     =
      (
        SELECT MAX(EFFDT) FROM PS_ACAD_PROG WHERE EMPLID=A.EMPLID
      )
  AND A.EFFSEQ=
    (
      SELECT
        MAX(EFFSEQ)
      FROM
        PS_ACAD_PROG
      WHERE
        EMPLID =A.EMPLID
      AND EFFDT=A.EFFDT
    )
     AND A.PROG_STATUS='AC'
     AND A.ADMIT_TERM ='1701';
  COMMIT;
END SRM_H_PROC;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi Tejash ,
this was my first question on stackoverflow and i wasn't expected that it will be answered so fastly ,

Comment: Hi @HariomSingh, Welcome to the stackoverflow!!

Comment: Both methods :
1-using cursor
2-without cursor

is working fine thanks a lot .

CHEERS..